# how to get a maximum of a transformed array

Tags: perl

Newbie alert. The following:

```
use List::Util qw(max);
use List::MoreUtils qw(apply);

my @list = ( 
        { 'name' => 'foo' , 'value' => 3 } , 
        { 'name' => 'bar' , 'value' => 31 } , 
        { 'name' => 'longname' , 'value' => -33 } , 
        { 'name' => 'grill' , 'value' => 333 } , 
        );

 print max apply { length $_->{name} } @list;
```

Outputs,

```
HASH(0x2e47c28)
```

Instead of `8`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not terribly clear from the `List::MoreUtils` documentation, but you have to assign to `$_` in the code block to get the value to propagate out. So change the code block to `{ $_ = length $_->{name} }` and it works.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need `apply` in this case because `length` doesn't modify the list items:

```
print max map { length $_->{name} } @list;
```